# PC "sleeps" (screen off, no reaction, but still running) and it won't wake up

Tags: windows-10, sleep, desktop, hibernate, switch

**Short description of the problem first:**

After being on for a while, my computer will show a black screen as if it were in hibernate mode or something (it's still on, the fans are still turning, but it doesn't react) and I can't wake it up.

**Long description of all the facts**, since I don't know which of them is causing the problem:

I have a desktop computer and a laptop which share a screen, keyboard and mouse via a switch. (I.e.: Screen, keyboard and mouse are attached to switch. Switch is connected to Laptop (via Docking station) via USB, and to Deskop. I can switch between the two by pressing Ctrl twice).
What I like to do is let my desktop render something over longer periods of time, sometimes over night, while I work on my laptop, just occasionally switching back to check.

I recently noticed that, when I switch back to the desktop, the screen just stays dark. The screen says it has no signal. I wonder if the Desktop PC has gone to sleep or something. But tapping the power button, clicking the mouse or pressing a keyboard key, which sometimes causes a computer to wake up, does nothing. I don't see how to wake it up. So so far, I just shut it off and restarted it, figuring I was just making some kind of minor mistake.

Recently though, the problem has become more frequent: instead of going to sleep (or whatever it's doing) after being turned on for a long time, say, overnight, it goes to sleep seemingly within minutes of being turned on. One time as I turned it on, it didn't start up properly, instead showing a white stripe. Turned it off and back on again and that worked. But the next time, it didn't boot anymore at all. I tracked the problem down to a faulty RAM, replayed it, and was happy my computer was starting again.

But now after leaving it on over night, I once again find it in this hibernate-like state where it won't wake up again. The motherboard isn't showing any errors that I can see (it has a digital display where it can show an error number code), and the MemOK DRAM LED that would glow red if there's a problem with the RAM is also turned off.

Facts that could help diagnosis:

- The Desktop runs Windows 10.
- The Desktop has been running fine for several years before it started acting weird
- When in this "sleep mode", The motherboard displays "AA". One side of the power button blinks, which it also does when it's running fine.
- The Desktop is supposed to be rendering something on sheepit-renderfarm.com. I can login there with my laptop and see that the desktop's connected. When it's in that sleepmode, it's no longer connected.

I would also be grateful for a way to diagnose it further, to figure out what state the PC is in. What I also wonder: Could my computer's flawed state have somehow destroyed the previous RAM, or was it just coincidense the RAM died at the same time? (Obviously the faulty RAM couldn't have caused the computer's problem, cause the problems persist with the new RAM)

Things I tried:

- It's obviously not because the Screen or mouse are badly connected, or else things wouldn't work with my laptop either. And the switch must be properly connected to the desktop cause it sometimes works
- In the power settings, it's set to "Go to sleep: Never"
- I tried pressing Ctrl+Alt+B, and Windows key + X, which seem to be the combination to wake windows 10 up. It doesn't react.
- Once it's in this sleep-like state, I also tried connecting screen, keyboard and mouse directly to the desktop instead of the switch, to see if I can wake it up that way. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Separate the laptop and desktop completely (no sharing), and then determine if either or both are causing issuess

Comment: Why would the laptop be causing issues? The Laptop never goes black, whether it's on its own or connected to the switch system. Are you suggesting the laptop may be interfering with the Desktop via the switch?

Comment: On the laptop, update BIOS, Chipset, Power Driver and Video drivers using the Manufacturer's Driver Update app. Disable Hibernation and Hybrid Sleep. Restart and see if the laptop suspends  properly

Comment: " What I like to do is let my desktop render something over longer periods of time, sometimes over night, while I work on my laptop, just occasionally switching back to check"    -    If this is all you need, you should use remote desktop to check your desktop occasinonally - Is the reason to use the switch that they are not on the same network?

Comment: With monitor KVM switch, anything can happen, may be the reason is in the KVM switch.

Comment: John: You did get that it's the Desktop that has these problems where it goes to sleep and doesn't wake up again, not the laptop, right? But I guess I can try those things on the desktop.

Comment: jw_ : No, the laptop and Desktop are right next to each other, on the same desk. I like to use an external screen and external keyboard when I work on the laptop cause it's more comfortable. But I also need a screen and keyboard for the desktop. Obviously I don't want 2 screens and 2 keyboards on my desk, so I switch back and forth. And a switch seems so much easier than constantly changing all the cables back and forth.

Ok, I'll see if the issues happen when the switch is not involved. But this issue can't actually cause permanent damage to the Desktop, right?

Comment: This is the switch I use btw: https://www.digitec.ch/de/s1/product/roline-dual-head-dvi-usb-20-1-user-2-pc-kvm-switch-5621374

Comment: I just went to the device manager and updated everything, which turned out to be a bad idea cause then windows didn't start anymore. Then I reinstalled windows (without losing my data btw, cause I didn't reformat the hard drive) and now it starts again. But the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

I took the computer to be repaired. The issue was: one of my two graphics cards was defective. (The second one. Not even the one into which I had the video cable plugged in)

By the way, something which could have given that away also was:

- When the screen went off, the fans on the graphics cards stopped turning, whereas the other ones continued.
- One time I had music running, and after the screen went black, the music continued for a few seconds, though it died soon after. I play sounds for that PC through my screen, and my screen only plays sounds when it's also receiving a visual image, so normally the sound disappears at the same time as the picture. But connect an audio cable to the broken PC, and a visual cable that transfers the picture from some healthy computer onto the screen, and you'll hear the music from the broken one.